# Larger script file fails but smaller seems to be ok

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-hover

[Here is fiddlelink where my result page is ok](http://jsfiddle.net/BQ9jw/) and [and there is bad page but more 'advanced'](http://jsfiddle.net/BQ9jw/1/).

Why doesn't the page respond correctly after I added:

```
$('#progressbar').progressbar({
  value: 37;
});
$('#acces a').click(function(){
  $('#mask').fadeIn('fast');
  $('#game').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code:
It should be

```
.progressbar({value:37});
```

instead of

```
.progressbar({value:37;});
```

Comment: tons of questions and wondering why the heck the page doesn't work correctly. Never would think about it! thanks ;P I feel embarrassed :(